Is it possible to invoke chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab to take screenshot when user open new tab without clicking extension icon?
I'm building a chrome extension and I want to implement the function users can take screenshot automatically when they open new tab. I want to achieve it without invoking the extension(by clicking extension icon).
My current code is as below. I can take screenshot when I switch tabs, but I get error when I open new tab. Error is:
`The 'activeTab' permission is not in effect because this extension has not been in invoked.`

//background.js
const captureScreenshot = (tabId) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab) => {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError && tab && tab.status === "complete") {
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, { format: "png" }, (dataUrl) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Screenshot captured for tab ID:", tabId);
        console.log("Screenshot data URL:", dataUrl);
      });
    } else {
      console.warn("Unable to capture screenshot for tab ID:", tabId);
      console.warn("Tab status:", tab ? tab.status : "unknown");
    }
  });
};

//take screenshot when user switch tab, it works.
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Tab activated:", activeInfo);

    captureScreenshot(activeInfo.tabId);
  }, 500);
});

//take screenshot when user open new tab. it doesn't work
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("New tab created:", tab);
    captureScreenshot(tab.id);
  }, 500);
});

I guess I can't use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab when it's new tab, without clicking extension icon.
So I'm thinking it might be possible with html2canvas and read this  . But it's not so obvious how to achieve my goal with this..
